# Typescript: Class extends a Generic Type

Tags: typescript

I know it's too generic, but I wish to make a class that would have all props and prototype from a generic type like this:

```
class GenericExtend<T> extends T {
    constructor(data: T) {
        // here is a workaround to make these 2 classes unique
        const proto = { ...GenericExtend.prototype };
        Object.assign(proto, Object.getPrototypeOf(data));
        Object.setPrototypeOf(this, proto);
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }

    GenericMethod() { }
}
```

And now on, I could instanciate `GenericExtend` class and then get the types of the two classes like this:

```
const obj = new GenericExtend<Model>(data);
obj.GenericMethod(); // ok
obj.ModelMethod(); // good!
```

One of my solution is to use intersection, something like this:

```
const obj: GenericExtend & Model = new GenericExtend(data) as any;
```

It worked, but I didn't like that much. Is there something better that I can do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

TypeScript will not let you implement or extend another type `T` unless all the keys of `T` are statically known at compile time.  That prevents `class GenericExtend<T> implements T {...}`  from being something you can write.

Instead, you have to use an intersection to get this behavior... but you can confine the type assertion to the constructor function, if you want, so that subsequent uses will not require it.  Let's rename `GenericExtend` out of the way:

```
class _GenericExtend<T> {
  constructor(data: T) {
    const proto = { ..._GenericExtend.prototype };
    Object.assign(proto, Object.getPrototypeOf(data));
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, proto);
    Object.assign(this, data);
  }
  GenericMethod() { }
}
```

And then redefine `GenericExtend` as both a type and a constructor with the intersection behavior you want:

```
type GenericExtend<T> = _GenericExtend<T> & T;
const GenericExtend: new <T>(data: T) => GenericExtend<T> = _GenericExtend as any;
```

That last `as any` is the type assertion we need.  Now you should be able to get the behavior you want:

```
interface Model {
  ModelMethod(): void;
}
declare const data: Model;

const obj = new GenericExtend(data);
obj.GenericMethod(); // ok
obj.ModelMethod(); // ok
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAED6DiBTAdogTgS2AUQB4BcUATAHgBUA+aAbwFgAoaaYAe2QnzQFdh8W0AFETD4wALmhkAlDQZMmrdvmgAHNCz7QAvDWgA6AwhToseQsiJ61GjQE8ViaAF8A3HPkB5AEYArRLz1ICAwAc2QBaz4AGmhvPwCQxHwABXU+fHtEDwAzIREwKSk3Rk9ff3w9CCTUmwyHHIF8AAsMCBjIliL3JjjywKhQ8ObWmOFRLpKndyRUTGAAWSSmliIBGWpnBin6OscZkxwCYnIqHSNZ0yOLE+gAMklixQ5ofbmzYglUAHdoE7zRCTSbRUV6XcykSjaOCgw7g6CQeHIWzFBgMDDIQhobJgYCOeYrRAgWQlfFEQmLZorNYSABuLAwRGK2zJoDAaEcT2UY3E0FJhJR9E50BYvih3xexjeV1W3ImIp8ehhFOWqyK0AA9OrhQBrBjyvR8kDKqlqzU6oA)

Comment: Great! Will it work if Model is a class, not an interface?

Comment: It should work syntactically, and the resulting object should match the class type structurally, but it might not work with things like `instanceof` or class prototype properties. That stuff needs to be worked out in the implementation of the `GenericExtend` constructor... I wouldn’t trust myself to write that.   It sounds like you might be looking for [mixins](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html) if your use case is to extend a class.

Comment: You're right! I guess mixins will resolve my problem.

Comment: Thanks for this solution @jcalz. I simplified it further to avoid the extra type and the cast to any:

`const GenericExtend = _GenericExtend as new <T>(data: T) => _GenericExtend<T> & T;`

Answer (score 2):

I came accross into the similar requirement and finally made it work in the following way, by which no intersection is strictly needed (you can define a dedicated type for type checking), hope it helps.

```
class A {
  a() {
    ...
  }
}

class B {
  b() {
    ...
  }
}

type Constructor = new (...args: any[]) => any

function genericExtend<T extends Constructor>(target: T) {
  return class GenericExtended extends target {
    constructor(...args: any[]) {
      super(...args)
    }

    genericMethod() {
      ...
    }
  }
}

const instanceOfA: GenericExtended & A = new (genericExtend(A))()
const instanceOfB = new (genericExtend(B))()

instanceOfA.a() // ok with type checking
instanceOfA.genericMethod() // ok with type checking

instanceOfB.b() // ok without type checking
instanceOfB.genericMethod() // ok without type checking
```