# Typescript: Type a class which wraps an object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a class which wraps an object. Like:

```
class Wrapper<T extends object> {
    constructor(private wrapped: T) {
    }
    // ...
    public extraMethod(){ return 2; }
}

let myWrapped = new Wrapper({a: 1}) as Wrapper<{a: number}> & {a: number};
console.log(myWrapped.a) // 1
console.log(myWrapped.extraMethod()) // 2
```

The flaw is with this line:

```
let myWrapped = new Wrapper({a: 1}) as Wrapper<{a: number}> & {a: number};
```

I have to be explicit about the typing. I have to tell TypeScript that this instance will be a `Wrapper` (thus has `extraMethod`), but also a custom object (thus has property `a`).

How could I tell TypeScript that every instance of class `Wrapper<T>` is of type `Wrapper` and also of type `T`?
With other words, how could I achieve if a variable has type `Wrapper<T>` to mean it is of type `Wrapper` and also of type `T`?

Thus the below would compile:

```
let myWrapped: Wrapper<{a: number}> = ...; // myWrapped is both of Wrapper and of {a: number}, without telling this explicitly via `as Wrapper<{a: number}> & {a: number}`
console.log(myWrapped.a)                   // comes from {a: number}
console.log(myWrapped.extraMethod())       // comes from Wrapper
```

Comment: Why not use a function instead?

Comment: The compiler will not allow you to do this with a `class` statement, since interfaces (like the instance side of a class) need to have statically known keys.  You can use type assertions to get `Wrapper` to be seen as the type you want, like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mMBodW) shows, but you'll find that such classes are themselves hard to extend, so whether that's useful depends on your use case.  See [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51567462/2887218) for more info.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz, this could work for me, my class won't need to be extended